# Add EC2 Tag to Multiple Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to add a new EC2 Tag with PowerShell to multiple instances at once. I have all of my instances tagged with the format

```
name : $Env_$Role_$Number
```

However, I failed to put a separate `Environment: Production` tag for each instance which I need now. I ran to following in PowerShell to get a list of the instances that I need in a table.

```
$ProdTag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter
$ProdTag.Name = "tag:Name"
$ProdTag.Values = "PROD*"
$Instances = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter
$Instances.Name = "tag:resource-type"
$ProdTag.Values = "instance"
Get-EC2Tag -Filter ($ProdTag, $Instances)
```

This outputs the list of instances I want. How would I grab the `ResourceType` column, store it in an array and apply `New-EC2Tag -tag (Name="tag: Environment, Value="Production:)` to that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I could store `Get-EC2Tag -Filter ($ProdTag, $Instances)` as an object in Powershell: `$ProdInstances = (Get-EC2Tag -Filter ($ProdFilter, $InstanceFilter)).ResourceID`

Then I created a `$ProdEnvTag` object to apply `Environment:Production` as a tag to everything in the `$ProdInstances` object: `$ProdInstances | ForEach-Object {New-EC2Tag -Resource $_ -Tag $ProdEnvTag}`

Answer (score 0):

Use Tag Editor AWS service. you can filter (or) select all EC2 instances and create a tag like ENV=DEV and apply on resources. its very useful.